# go rpc, http or websockets,which is fastest for transferring many small pieces of data, repeatedly, from one server to another

Tags: performance, http, go, websocket, rpc

**Background**

I'm experimenting creating a memory + cpu profiler in go, and wish to transfer the information quickly, maybe every second, from the program/service being profiled to a server which will do all of the heavy lifting by saving the data to a database and/or serving it via http to a site; this will reduce the load on the program being profiled for more accurate measurements. It will be small pieces of data being transferred. I know there are some libraries out there already, but like I said, experimenting.

**Transfer Content Type**

I have not decided on a concrete transfer type but looks like JSON for HTTP or Websockets and just the Struct for RPC (if I've done my research correctly)

**Summary**

I will likely try each just to see for myself, but have little experience using RPC and Websockets and would like some opinions or recommendations on which may be faster or more suitable for what I'm trying to do:

- HTTP
- RPC
- Websockets
- Anything else I'm not thinking about

Comment: but the most important is your DB.

Comment: Is the server you send data to a webserver? Is transport restricted to HTTP only? Is it written in Go? Do you want your solution be portable across different technologies or may it be tied to Go?

Comment: Jiang, the DB doesn't really matter at this point. icza, the data is just being sent to another server running a go program, could be a webserver, but also could just be a program. No transport is not restricted to HTTP. Yes it is written in go. It is completely OK to be tied to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, HTTP is not a requirement.

In this case in search for the fastest transferring solution I would completely drop the HTTP transport layer and would use just plain (TCP) socket connections as HTTP gives quite a big overhead just for transferring a few bytes.

Define your own protocol (which may be very simple), open a TCP connection to the server, and send the data packets every seconds or so as your requirements dictate.

Your protocol for sending (and receiving) data can be as simple as:

- Do an optional authenticating or client/server identification (to ensure you connected to the server/program you wanted to).
- Use the [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) packgae from the standard library to send data in binary form over the connection.

So basically the profiled program (client) should open the TCP connection, and use [`gob.NewEncoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#NewEncoder) wrapping the connection to send data. The server should accept the incoming TCP connection and use [`gob.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#NewDecoder) to wrapping the connection to recieve data.

Client calls [`Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Encoder.Encode) so send profiling info, it can be typically a struct value. Server calls [`Decoder.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Decoder.Decode) to receive a profiling info, the struct that the client sent. That's all.

Sending data in binary form using the `encoding/gob` package requires you to use the same type to describe the profiling data on both sides. If you want more flexibility, you may also use the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to send/receive profiling info as JSON text. The downside is that JSON will require more data to be sent and it takes more time to produce and parse the JSON text compared to the binary representation.

If loosing some profiling packets (or recieving duplicates) is not an issue, you may want to try/experiment using UDP instead of TCP which may be even more efficient.

Comment: UDP is a good suggestion. Might also consider Google Protocol Buffers to simplify your codecs.

Comment: @Nicholas If profiling data is captured/described as a Go `struct`, Google Protocol Buffer would just complicate it and slow it down (you can send and recieve a `struct` with one simple method call using `encoding/gob`, requiring nothing from your part).

Comment: Perfect Thanks, Exactly what I was looking for!